# How to clear an ArrayList object java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to Java, so this has come across in a beginner java problem.

I am aware that it is bad practice to leave an object open once it is no longer in use, however I cannot find an example of this for an ArrayList: the tutorials I have looked at leave it open and I can't find anything other than clearing it to remove all items in it.

I am looking for the equivalent to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = sc.nextLine();
sc.close();
```

but for the ArrayList object:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
countries.add("Spain");
countries.add("China");
System.out.println(countries);
//And then something like
countries.close();
```

Is it just `ArrayList<Object>.clear()`? but that doesn't remove the object?

Comment: Resources in java can be closed and those are marked by implementing the Closeable interface. Normal classes/objects like ArrayList don't. An ArrayList is never "open" or "closed". That doesn't make much sense in that context.

Comment: "it is bad practice to leave an object open once it is no longer in use" Maybe for something like a file resource, but it is absolutely normal just to leave ArrayLists lying around when done.

Comment: As an aside, it is generally a bad idea to close a scanner which wraps `System.in`, as it will close the standard input of your application, which means you can not accept any more input for the remainder of your program run.

Answer (score 2):

> I am aware that it is bad practice to leave an object open once it is no longer in use, however I cannot find an example of this for an ArrayList ...

It is NOT **in general** (a) "bad practice" to leave objects "open".

Failing to close certain kinds of objects can cause problems, but these are all objects that are associated with external or non-heap resources.  The most common examples are:

- Objects that have an associated file descriptor; e.g. `Socket`, `FileInputStream` and `FileOuputStream`.
- Objects that have an associated "connection" to an external service; e.g. JDBC `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` objects.
- Objects that have associated off-heap storage; e.g. `BufferedImage`.

However, most Java objects *don't* have this problem, and you *don't* need to "close" them.  Indeed, most objects don't have a `close()` or `dispose()` method.

`ArrayList` is typical.  It is not necessary to "close" or "clean" an `ArrayList`.  Just leave it for the garbage collector to clean up.

In exception circumstances, it *might* be advisable to clean a `List` object; e.g.  so that you can reuse it.   If you need to do that, call the `clear()` method.

However, that is generally a bad idea.  In the case of `ArrayList`, calling `clear()` can lead to first and second order performance issues:

1. Clearing a list entails touching all of the list cells.  That consumes CPU time.
2. The `clear()` method does not resize the `ArrayList` backing array.  So a recycled list that becomes large will continue to have a large backing array ... for ever ... if you keep recycling it.
3. With most Java GC's, a Java object that survives a number of GC cycles will be promoted to the "old" generation.  When that happens, the associate GC costs increase.  For example, when you assign a reference to a new object to an old object (say our list) that causes the new object (and possibly nearby objects) to NOT be collected in the next new space collection; i.e. it extends its lifetime.

In short, `clear()` can be bad for performance.

---

> But that doesn't [`List.clear()`] remove the object?

No.  It doesn't remove it.  It "empties" the list, but the list object still exists, and can still be used.

---

Beware of good / best / bad practice advice.  A lot of it is "snake oil".  And even at the best of times, most such advice doesn't apply universally.  People who like to rely on so-called "best practice" advice (or offer it!) should read this:

- [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164)

Answer (score 0):

Using `.clear()` will remove all items from the list, but it looks like you want to tell the garbage collector to delete the object.  As far I know, there is no way to do this.  However, there is also no need to worry about deleting objects.  If your code stops using them, the garbage collector will simply delete them from memory automatically.

Comment: Of course there's `System.gc()` but of course you should never use it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, ArrayList can be left open and if you want to remove all the objects from the List you can use **.clear** function. Generally streams implement the closable interface and needed to be closed. Reason we try to write the efficient code by reducing the space complexity because the lists remain in the code as it is.

Comment: _"In general, ArrayList can be left open"_, you don't even have a choice in that, as there is nothing to close with an array list (it doesn't even have a concept of being "open", so using that terminology is even confusing).

Comment: yes Right Mark, There is no concept like being open. This opening closing concept doesn't exist in List. I meant ArrayLists can be left as it is. Thanks for clearing out the confusion.